# Lilypond: Changing \partCombine on a system-by-system basis

Tags: lilypond, engraving

In Dorico and many published scores (such as [this Mahler score](https://clara.imslp.org/en/library/pdf?itemId=1698028236456-ACA4AB4F6697B33D)), there is condensing where instruments are displayed in multiple voices and can 'separate' out when necessary. For example, on the 2nd page of the linked score, the Clarinet in A is grouped in 1.2.3 in system one and then Clarinet in A 1 and Clarinet in A 2.3.

I know there is `\partCombine` in LilyPond, but there is no way to change the combination (in addition to the staff labels) on a system-by-system basis. If there is any way (even a long workaround), it would be greatly appreciated. I have attached an image here so you can see what I mean.

[image: The previously described Clarinets in Mahler 9].

Comment: I was under the impression that `partCombine` wasn't able to combine three or more parts at a time anyhow.  (Maybe I was misinformed, though.)